# "Cast is redundant" warning when returning negated bool

Tags: c#, casting, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

The following program compiles fine in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, but a "Cast is redundant" warning is generated:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        bool negated = p.NegateBool(true);
    }

    public bool NegateBool(object value)
    {
        // "Cast is redundant" warning.
        return !(bool)value;

        // No warning.
        //return (bool)value;

        // No warning.
        //var negated = !(bool)value;
        //return negated;
    }
}
```

When accepting the "Quick Fix" suggestion to remove the cast, the program no longer compiles.

This is only happening when the cast is done directly in the return statement and the negation operator is used.

If the result is put into a variable and then returned, no warning is generated.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You should probably file a bug report with the Roslyn team. They're on Github and very helpful, usually.

Comment: Yep, please file a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn if you haven't already.

Comment: I have filed a bug report now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the Roslyn compiler.

I have filed a bug report on Github and the problem will be fixed in a future version:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10311

Answer (score -2):

bool negated = p.NegatedBool(true);

compiler already knows that you are passing and boolean at this point.
try truee instead of true and it will give you an error. and if you type true compiler knows that its a boolean from system.boolean , just hover your mouse over true. 
 so now the compiler already knows that its an bool.
just put a debug point on your methods first line. thats the opening curly brace , and go to debug. if your add a watch on value you will know it may show something like this object{bool} in its type.

Comment: The argument to `NegateBool` is of type `object`. This sounds like a Roslyn bug.

Comment: hmmm... well i think he should declare his method as public bool NegateBool(bool value). thats  one way..

Comment: This isn't about questionable programming praxis. Yes, the code as it stands is unnecessary complicated. And yes, it could be simplified. But that's not the point. This is about weird behaviour of an analyzer and quick fix, which suggests a change that prevents the program from compiling. The code they have there is likely already a minimal example and not taken verbatim from an actual project.